# QGIS Cartogram3 plugin

Tags: qgis

I'm using QGIS 3.16. Everytime I run the cartogram3 plugin, six more QGIS windows open and the plugin doesn't run. Here is a screenshot. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: it looks as if it is running, a very detailed coastline like that one may take a while to process.

Comment: Generalize your polygons before, use Grass v.generalize (to keep topology) or stick to an already genralized dataset - have a look e.g. at https://gadm.org . To create cartograms, another option is the great OpenSource standalone application Scapetoad: http://scapetoad.choros.place - it's easy to use and you can export the results to reimport it to QGIS.